# Cannot display the list of names into the view

Tags: c#, list, view

I have a list that I prepare in a ViewModel to take values from database table. The list assigned into a model class:

```
public class DType
{
    public string DTName { get; set; }
}
```

And it get updated by the following method:

```
public static List<DType> GetDocTypesString(Entity DB, int RKey)
    {
        return DB.Database.SqlQuery<DType>(@"SELECT * FROM Names
                                                     WHERE NK = {0}", RKey).ToList();
    }
```

And then I return the list (model) to the view to list the names into a select menu as the following:

The actual returned model to the view:

```
public List<DType> ihName { get; set; }
```

it gets populated by using the method above:

```
ihName = GetDocTypesString(DB, RKey);
```

And then, in the view, I use the below:

```
@Html.Partial("GettingNamesPartial", new ProjName.ViewModels.UploadingPartialViewModel
            {
                DropdownIHDocType = new SelectList(Model.ihEditorInstanceName)
            })
```

The results are always like this:

Instead to displaying the actual names, the list (select) display:

```
ProjName.ViewModels.DType
ProjName.ViewModels.DType
ProjName.ViewModels.DType
ProjName.ViewModels.DType
```

The only thing that matches is the number of items is the same as the names on the database table.

**Important Note:**
Before trying to pull the names from the database, the list worked just fine by hard coding the names like the following:

```
DropdownIHDocType = new SelectList(new string[] { "Morgan", "Sam", "Shawn" })
```

Comment: Where is the markup where you are trying to display these items?  The problem is you are displaying the whole object, not a property/properties of the object (i.e `DtName`)

Answer (score -1):

```
ihName = GetDocTypesString(DB, RKey);
```

is your culprit. your getting a list of document types, not the variable `name` from each of those documents. basically your showing the class not its content. you need to get access to the actual document, then find the variable you need and assign that to `ihName`

so you're grabbing DType not DType.DTname which is what i assume your trying to list

Comment: I am fairly certain this is _not_ the OPs problem.  This returns a list, just like they expect.  The problem is how they display the list...

Comment: its not how they display the list its the list they are displaying thats wrong. hes getting a list of document types and he wants the names in those documents not the types.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the question.  The OP wants to retrieve the entire object from the method, but only wants to display the `DTName`  property in the view

Comment: its possible i am misunderstanding but it still looks like hes populating his list with the class of the objects in the database not the actual objects.

Comment: The method returns `List<DType>` which is correct.  The class `DType` has a property called `DTName`, this is what OP wants to see in the view.  The reason they see the class name/namespace is because the default implementation of `ToString()` on a class is to just spit out the namespace and class.  [See here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vytJJo)

Comment: uh huh. where is he using ToString() so generically? maybe i missed it. and thats exactly what im saying, wherever hes calling that ToString() he need to adjust it to grab his variable not the whole class.

Comment: We dont know where OP is using `ToString()` or something similar because the OP has not included a [MCVE].  Without that the question is unanswerable.

Comment: what are you talking about nobody said anything about overriding

Comment: somewhere he is populating List<DType> right? so that is where the mistake is, in that method he is adding the class, maybe as you say using ToString, but he needs to return the actual object and then grab the variable.... i think you and i are in agreement about most of this...

Comment: no i get what your saying... and i agree. Code on Brother! lol

Comment: `DB.Database.SqlQuery<DType>("...").ToList();`  is where the List is populated.  This is fine, this is _exactly_ what they want to do.  The list here will have the `DTName` property populated.  The issue is that the OP is _not displaying_ the name because they are instead displaying the _instance_.  It literally just boils down to the markup in the view that OP has not shown.

Comment: ` DropdownIHDocType = new SelectList(Model.ihEditorInstanceName)` here he is adding instance names to the dropdown, is this what you mean?

Comment: Well we dont actually know what that is doing because `Model.ihEditorInstanceName` isnt defined anywhere in the OPs post. This is why I voted to close the question because it does not contain a [MCVE]